# Selenium web scraping information into a list

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to scrape ISBN numbers from the following website link:  http://bookscouter.com/tools/recent.php

I wanted to scrape the ISBN numbers from the bold plaintext of each of the books in the list and put them all into an array.  I was going to do this by using xPath but that's where I got a little stuck.  Since I'm new to selenium w/Java I'm having a hard time understanding how to get the whole thing working.  I know each of the ISBN numbers for the individual books are located in a table class called "recent-table" but I'm not entirely familiar with how to go from there. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the text including ISBN

The following code will wait for 10s for all the elements loaded and return a list. After that print the text of all elements.

```
By byXpath = By.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'ISBN')]");

List<WebElement> iSBNList = (new WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(byXpath)));

for (WebElement element :iSBNList){
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This will help me out quite a lot.  So this code will return a list of just the first ISBN or of all the ISBN numbers on the page?  It looks like it's only the first ISBN but I wanted to confirm with you first.

Comment: @John123 It a list of all ISBN on the page